# MYSQL SELECT query very slow - use of JOIN possible?

Tags: mysql, performance, select

This working query is very slow (almost 30 sec execution) and I saw that the JOIN clause could improve speed.
Unfortunately I failed using it and this is where my knowledge stops...

Please, is there any way to improve execution speed (using JOIN or any other solution) ?

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT `club`,
COUNT(`club`),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `players` juniors WHERE `category` IN ('U11', 'U13', 'U15', 'U18') AND juniors.`club` = main.`club`),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `players` seniors WHERE `category` IN ('O40', 'O50', 'O60', 'O70') AND seniors.`club` = main.`club`)
FROM `players` main
GROUP BY `club`
```

Table `players` has 10'000 players.
Field `club` indicates which club they belong to.
Field `category` indicates the age category (Under 13, Over 40, ...).

I'd like to have a list of all clubs with following data :
club name, number of players in the club, number of juniors in the club, number of seniors in the club

Many thanks for your help !

Comment: You don't need `DISTINCT` when you're using `GROUP BY`.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry Why does he need part 2? His problem isn't with the results, it's with the speed.

Comment: Always prefer group by over distinct. Distinct is heavy than group by. you are using both. keep group by only.

Comment: Make sure you have indexes on the `club` and `category` columns.

Comment: You should normally use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(columnname)`, unless the column can be null and you need to omit those from the count.

Comment: @Barmar Only so others (well, me) can understand what's going on.

Comment: Have you looked at the `EXPLAIN` output to see how the query is being executed?

Comment: I didn't know the EXPLAIN statement and I'm trying it now with the documentation. Still haven't understood which are the useful parts, but it'll come with time. Thanks again everybody !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT club, COUNT(*) AS total,
    SUM(`category` IN ('U11', 'U13', 'U15', 'U18')) AS juniors,
    SUM(`category` IN ('O40', 'O50', 'O60', 'O70')) AS seniors
FROM players
GROUP BY club
```

Make sure you have indexes on the `club` and `category` columns.